# How do I send text to a dom object with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, text

Rather than population said DOM object with an external page such as HTML CFM or PHP, what if I simply want to send text?

I've tried:

$("#myDOMObject").val("some text");

No errors, but the object value doesn't update either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What element is "myDOMObject"? If it's a text input, your code should be working fine. If it's something else, use `$("#myDOMObject").text("some text");`

Comment: the element is a Div with id of myDOMObject, not truly, but for examples sake.  Anyway, I tried your format to no avail.  I can make it a text input I suppose, with no background/border.  I'm using it simply for a visual clue for the user. That their event is complete.

Comment: Gene R: Are you sure that using .text() did not work? Did any errors appear in your console?

Comment: @Gene R, John's example is right other than the space between 'text' and the '('

Comment: Chris: eh, that's just stylistic, but I'll change it if it's a bother.

Comment: No, you were right, I missed a quote... using .txt on the div did it

Thanks a ton

Comment: @Gene, I forgot js is that loose with the spacing and all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DOM object, you can simply do this:

```
jQuery(your_dom_object).text('Hello World!');
```

But, since you use jQuery anyway, I think you should just do

```
$('#the_id_of_your_dom_object').text('Hello World');
```

You can use any jQuery query instead of referencing the ID of the object directly. See the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com) for more details.